# How to pass data to twimlbin?

Tags: php, twilio

I am using twimlbin to host snippets of twiml php code.  Is it possible to pass data from an external php script into a twimlbin snippet when generating a call?

In the following code, $twimlbinurl is the publicly-accessible url for my snippet.  Can I pass additional data to the snippet through querystring args or some other method?

```
// Initiate a new outbound call
$call = $client->account->calls->create(
$phonefrom,     // The number of the phone initiating the call
$phoneto,       // The number of the phone receiving call
$twimlbinurl);      // The URL Twilio will request when the call is answered
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio Evangelist here. I don't think that's possible, TwiMLBin just hosts static content, so you can't do anything interactive with it at the other end.

I.E. if you add parameters to your TwiML, it will just ignore them and render the TwiML.

There are a lot of different ways you can get your own server setup, such as AWS, Heroku, EngineYard, and many, many more!

Hope this helps.